# How to find variance with change in observation?

Tags: statistics

The A.M and variance of 10 observations is 78 and 112 resp. Later, one observation is increased from 76 to 86. Determine in which two sets is the standard deviation more/higher.

I am not able to calculate the change in variance which i attribute to missing data of all observations. Is it not correct?
any help would be appreciated.

P.S ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. What happens to the mean when you change a value from 76 yo 86?
2. You do not need the all the data points to evaluate if the standard deviation increases or decreases. You need to look at just the contribution coming from this particular data point.

Comment: although the mean has increased by a small amount( by 1 to be precise), wont the  variance have a compounded effect of that change(as the values get squared). because, in theory it is understandable that the std. deviation and the variance would increase, but will we be able to find the exact value of that change? I have just started the introduction to statistics, so the concepts are not that strong. thanks for the reply. If the exact solution can be arrived at then a hint on that direction would be appreciated